# How can I truncate a table row

Tags: html

The content of a row is higher than the row itself. Is there a way to truncate?

I tried this:

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height:100px;overflow:hidden">
                <td>
                    <div style="height:400px; width:100px; background: yellow;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

but it did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can set a maximum height for a table row. For the `max-height` attribute in particular, there is documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530809%28VS.85%29.aspx) that explains that it cannot be used for tables. Do you specifically want to use tables? If not, there's always applying a `max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden;` to a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the table row to `display: block`

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height:100px;overflow:hidden;display:block">
            <td>
                <div style="height:400px; width:100px; background: yellow;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

If you want the table row to still act like a table row (`display: block` changes the row rendering) you should use nested `DIV` elements inside of the table cell instead:

```
<table style="border: solid blue 3px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="height:100px;overflow:hidden;border: solid black 3px;">
                   <div style="height:400px; width:100px; background: yellow;"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Code with preview here: http://jsfiddle.net/pYzRu/